# Keycloak language support

Tags: java, internationalization, keycloak

I'm using keycloak 2.5.1 to securise my web application, and it works really fine.
It currently supports 4 languages : english, french, german and italian.
I have received a new requirement to support dutch and latvian.
I follow the procedure described on Keycloak documentation in the Internationalization section of the themes paragraph ([here](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_development/topics/themes.html)), but it doesn't work at all, I cannot add those languages in the admin console.
As soon as I understand, there was a ticket on that problem but it was solved.
But I also see on the web that there are lots of problems with that specific aspect in Keycloak.

Has anybody an idea on how to make it work or about a possible error in Keycloak documentation ?

Thank you,

Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't enable Dutch (nl) either in Keycloak version 3.2.1 (where it is supported out of the box), but that was solved by upgrading to the latest version (3.4.0).